# Streaming cameras by ip with python

Tags: python, camera, opencv

I have a remote camera streaming through rtsp protocol and am trying to access it in OpenCV 2.13.1 using python with following code.

```
camera = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://admin:<pass>@<ip>:<port>/xyz/video.smp")
```

However, when I do that I get the following warning

```
[tcp @ 00000188ed4e9b00] Connection to tcp://ip failed: Error number -138 occurred
warning: Error opening file (/build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:901)
warning: http://ip (/build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:902)
```

I dont know how to fix that

Comment: Shouldn't it be `rtsp://user:<pass>@<ip>:<port>/xyz/video.smp` ? in your example code you put the port after the username

Comment: yes, sorry I will edit

Comment: It looks like it is not able to establish a connection, could it be that the port is not opened? firewall? or maybe closed for TCP connections? or  that is not the link for the rtsp (or is not broadcasting in rtsp). Can you access it with another app, like VLC?

Comment: @api55 no, i just acces for browser with internet explorer, anda in this ip I have four cameras in a dvr, i dont know if thats inflcuene in something

Comment: Sometimes the link needs extra params to get the rtsp video stream. For instance, some cameras have a get param like `?channel=2` or sometimes is in the url like `ip:port\11`. Also, you should make sure that the port is the rtsp one not the one for the browser, by default is 554 and if you do not set any I think ffmpeg will try that one. If you tell the model of the DVR/camera, I may try to help you on the link, but it could also be a firewall problem (in internet explorer plugin, I think they do it differently....

Comment: The port is 3777 i already see this and the model of the DVR/Camera is intelbrass cvd1004

Comment: I think it is this url, can you try it? `rtsp://[username]:[password]@[ip]:[port]/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0` I think channel is the cam and subtype is the main or secondary stream (0 and 1 respectively)

Comment: Same error with subtype = 1 or 0, but now returns this errors to

cv2.error: OpenCV(4.0.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:350: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'